# Dynamically Create and Delete Div tag using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to create 3 Div tags Dynamically when I press 3 different buttons (Red Green Blue).. When I press Red I want the height of 'red' div to be the size of my screen so that whole page appears to be red and when I press Green I want the height of the 'red' div to become 50% of my screen and other 50% of the screen should be occupied by other div (which is Green)..

And finally when I press Blue button I want All the divs to appear on screen with equal height...

I'm able to create the divs but I can't delete the previously created div when I press Red button after pressing all three buttons...

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
        <title>Ass 2</title>

        <script type="text/javascript">

        function fblue() {
            // document.bgColor = 'lightblue';

            selc=document.getElementById("first");
            divBlue=document.getElementById("one");
            myPara.removeChild(divBlue);



             selc=document.getElementById("first");

             divBlue=document.createElement("div");
             divBlue.id = "one";
             divBlue.style.backgroundColor = "lightblue";
             divBlue.style.height = "610px"
             divBlue.innerHTML = "dv tag created successfully";

             selc.appendChild(divBlue);
        }

        function fgreen() {

            selc=document.getElementById("first");
            divBlue=document.getElementById("one");


            divBlue.id = "one";
            divBlue.style.backgroundColor = "lightblue";
            divBlue.style.height = "305px"
            divBlue.innerHTML = "dv tag created successfully";
            selc.appendChild(divBlue);

            divGreen=document.createElement("div");
            divGreen.id = "one";
            divGreen.style.backgroundColor = "lightgreen";
            divGreen.style.height = "305px"
            divGreen.innerHTML = "dv tag created successfully";
            selc.appendChild(divGreen);

            //document.bgColor = ''; 
        }

        function fred() {

            document.getElementById("one").style.backgroundColor = 'lightblue';
            document.getElementById("one").style.width = '1104px';
            document.getElementById("one").style.height = '185px';

            document.getElementById("two").style.backgroundColor = 'red';
            document.getElementById("two").style.width = '1104px';
            document.getElementById("two").style.height = '185px';

            document.getElementById("three").style.backgroundColor = 'lightgreen';
            document.getElementById("three").style.width = '1104px';
            document.getElementById("three").style.height = '185px';
            document.bgColor = ''; 
        }

        </script>
    </head>
    <body style="margin: 0px;">
        <div style="height: 0px;" id="first"></div>

        <div id="four" style="margin-left: 415px; margin-top: 500px">
            <form>
                <input type="button" name="blu" value="Blue" onclick="javascript:fblue();">
                <input type="button" name="gre" value="Green/Red" onclick="javascript:fgreen();">
                <input type="button" name="re" value="Red/Green/Blue" onclick="javascript:fred();">
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: how are you calculating heights for your three divs

Comment: if I were you i'd read http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/2045-distinction-between-local-and-global-variables-javascript/ before worrying about divs and sizes

Comment: WOW!! People are already rating my question -4 ! What's my fault??

The only problem I'm facing right now is even after using "element.removeChild(child); it is not being deleted....... This made me ask a question here... My mistake..

Comment: @NayeemJunaid: because the way you have pasted your code was in really bad shape.

Comment: @defau1t I always face problem pasting the code over here.. Why can't it be simple like other sites to paste some code in quotess??

Comment: It is very simple, just paste your code select all and then in the text editor click the quotes and you are done. You can also see the preview while posting question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
  document.createElement("div");
```

will create a div dynamiclly

```
var oldChild = element.removeChild(child);
element.removeChild(child);
```

Removes a child node from the DOM. Returns removed node.

Comment: why create a variable "oldChild" when you don't use it?

Comment: In javascript to remove the child you need to refer the parent of that element. If you can tell me how you have calculate the heights of your divs. I can show you how to append and remove in a fiddle.